# Can I get the error per output during training?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a neural network (regression) with 3 output values. During training, I get a single RMSE value indicating the performance of the predictions on the test data. Is there a way that I can get the error per output value for the test data instead? That is, I get 3 RMSE values, one for each output.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=root_mean_squared_error)

def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.sqrt(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))
```